# Doesn't show supported letters

Tags: html, css, google-webfonts

I'm using [Signika Bold](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Signika) as font for my headers. Font is loaded from Google Webfonts. As you can see in [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vule/6rdj6/), there is a problem with showing letter "Č", both upper and lower case. The letter is on the list of supported fonts on the official Webfonts page.

[image]

***CSS:***

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Signika";
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 700;
   src: local("Signika-Bold"), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/signika/v3/7M5kxD4eGxuhgFaIk95pBRsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format("woff");
}

h1 {
   font-family: "Signika", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

I have also tried typing the letter as HTML entitle (`&#269;`), but it doesn't help.

Comment: http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/9917/a0d3.png check this on google font settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Anon, the solution is to check the Latin Extended in the Google font settings. [The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vule/6rdj6/1/) is updated.

***CSS:***

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Signika';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 700;
   src: local('Signika-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/signika/v3/F587cG5P5ff3TX6w4JlorxsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Or:

***HTML:***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:700&subset=latin,latin-ext">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:700&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```